# Is there an USB-Hub that allows simultaneous sharing?

Tags: networking, usb, hub

I have been looking for a device to connect printer, smartcard, etc. to two PCs at the same time. I've heard that there'd be a file corruption issue, but maybe they worked out a workaround. Unfortunately my search turned out empty why I am now here.

Right now I am working with a hub which has to switch control over devices. Is there a switch-less alternative? Ideally not costly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you would not be able to do this directly. The long short of it is that even if you found a way to connect everything, one computer isn't aware of what the other is doing, and so assumptions it would make about device states fail. Also the devices themselves likely aren't prepared to be controlled by multiple hosts at once, and USB isn't designed for this type of usage. Plus a host of other difficulties. This paragraph doesn't do it justice.

You have a few options.

The cheapest (free) and easiest is probably to attach the printer to one of the PC's, then if you are using Windows enable file/print sharing and share the printer on the network, or if you are using another OS I'm sure there's a way to share printers. It will appear in the network device list of other PCs (Windows it will appear right away, I don't have a lot of experience setting up printers on other platforms). Storage can also be done this way; attach it to one computer then set it up as a shared folder and the second PC can access it remotely.

If this is not possible for whatever reason (e.g. physical placement of printer, unavailability of PCs, etc.), for a printer the solution is a network print server. This is essentially a device with a USB port to plug your printer into, and a wireless / wired network connection. Then everybody using it can configure it as a network printer. You can find many on [Amazon](http://amzn.to/UzMEvY), newegg, Tiger Direct, Best Buy, etc., generally in the $30 - $120 range. Check reviews and compatibility information if available (Amazon has a good return policy if you have issues, real-life stores like Best Buy are convenient as well).

Some printers have a network port in them or wifi capability already. Check if yours does, or buy one that does. My router has a USB port on the back and a built in print server.

For storage devices, if you can't use file sharing from one computer, your options will be potentially slightly more expensive than the printer setup ($60-$120) but [here is a good article reviewing various USB file servers](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2392221,00.asp).

And yes, your switch that you have now is not the safest option, when you hit the switch it's the exact same effect as pulling the USB connection out of the computer, so all the same caveats for file storage apply. If you always remember to eject the device from the computer before switching away you'll be fine, otherwise good luck. For printers it probably won't be an issue but you won't be able to do things like, e.g., queue print jobs from multiple computers at once.